# This class design is too close to the db table structure?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, database-design

I have a db with the following tables **Items**, **Groups** and **GroupItems**. The Items table contains the settings of each item, the groups table contains the definition of some groups and the GroupsItems table contains the link of each item to each group and the date when the item was added to the group and the date when the item was removed (if any).

In my C# model I have 3 classes:

- `class Item`
- `class Group`
- `class GroupItem`

The class Group has a collection of GroupItems and each GroupItem class contains one Item and the date added and removed if any.

I'm not sure if this is a good design or if I'm moving the DB structure to my application model. Would be better if I move the two dates directly to the class Item and I reduce the number of classes by one and thus the software complexity?

What do you think?

Comment: Do you use an O/RM? Which one?

Comment: No, I'm moving the data by 'hand' using a SqlClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If you can* by removing the `GroupItem` class and "splitting" it in `Item` in your architecture, it's a good choice. 
The only thing you have to consider, that you have to remap your DB mapping at this point.

The choice here is between **clean architecture** of your app and **clean mapping** between your app and DB.

I, personally, would stand for **clean mapping** and leave the stuff as is. As after a couple of month you will never remember which fild where binded, and having already *relatively* coherent mapping between your `code model` and `db model` will help make the *all stuff* easier to understand, **imo**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `GroupItem` is a **[qualified association](http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Qualified+Associations/)** between `Group` and `Item`.

The question you must ask yourself is whether you really need a qualified association, or not. Given the very generic names of your entites, I don't know. There are three cases to consider:

- If an item is held only by one group, you don't need a qualified association: the information (i.e. the date) in the association can be moved in the item. It's a simple *one-to-many* association. `Group` has a list of `Item` and you don't need an additional table (the table for `Item` has a *foreign key* to the group).
- If an item can be in several groups--which I guess is the case--then you can go for:

  - a *many-to-many* association. Each entity (`Item` or `Group`) has a list of entities of the other kind.
  - a *qualified* association. Qualified association are usually represented with a `HashMap` (`Date`, `Item`), or as you did, a special collection of `GroupItem`.

In the two latter variants, you need an additional table to model the association between `Group` and `Item` at the level of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Each class have a separate table is good segregation of concept.With this method you can  some **ORM** tool will help for good architecture.

And also some matured orm tools like **NHibernate** will provide different kind of class mapping like inheritance,composition,1-1 relation,1-many relation etc..So its better to use ORM tool for a good Domain Driven Development

Comment: I'm not doing DDD here and I do not plan to use ORM tools as the database tables are not so much and I like having control of what and how is done.